# Python executing commands in the command prompt (taskkill)

Tags: python, windows, command-line, os.system, taskkill

I'm trying to use `os.system` to use the taskkill command in command prompt. ill gut out the only part im having trouble with:

```
os.system('taskkill /s %s /u CORP\Administrator /p CLARiiON! /pid AxAuto.exe'%(connection[i]))
```

The variable `connection[i]` is just an IP Address of a remote computer on the same network. I can run this command straight from the command prompt locally and just directly input the IP and I know for a fact it will work, But running the command through Python in this format returns "> was unexpected at this time." Am I making a silly formatting mistake in this line of code? the error can be seen below:
[image: "> was unexpected at this time.]

**EDIT:** I've also been told to use the Subprocess module. i tried the snippet below:

```
command="taskkill /s %s /u CORP\Administrator /p CLARiiON! /im AxAuto.exe"%(connection[i]))
subprocess.Popen(command, stdout= subprocess.PIPE, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

It doesnt fail in the script but it also doesnt kill the process.

Comment: can you provide the exact error you're getting? Is the error a Windows error or a Python error?  Also you may want to use the ``subprocess`` module instead of ``os.system``.

Comment: @notorious the error I get is shown in the Python script window, there is no trace back it only says  "> was unexpected at this time." when it executes the command

Comment: @bladexeon I hope  you are aware that you have posted the password in your python code! ;-)

Comment: The `/pid` argument should be an integer value. You may use `/img` for an image name of the process. https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/taskkill.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: @pss But I have used the name of the process in a normal Windows cmd prompt and it worked saying "Process xxx has been killed" or something like that so I know this will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the code below:

```
from subprocess import call

call(['taskkill', '/s', connection[i], '/u', 'CORP\Administrator', '/py',
      'CLARiiON!', '/pid', 'AxAuto.exe'])
```

Comment: This one gave me:
`raise TypeError("This object does not support enumeration")`

Comment: This may be caused by ``connection``. What do you get when you print ``connection[i]``

Comment: Aha! gives me this: `<_wmi_namespace: ,COMObject <unknown>>>` this coming from a different part of the code...also being ssomething i have no idea how to fix

Comment: I don't think you need to "fix" it, you just need to figure out how to get the IP address from that object or even if it's possible.

Comment: I figured out the error I was using a `WMI` connection variable instead of the raw IP variable, and It did work with Subprocess. Thanks Much!